# all nodes fail to start up

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I set up my configuration files and formatted my file system already but whenever I try to execute the start shell scripts I get this error.

Below I put the alias for hstart

## Error:

```
computer:~ seanplowman$ hstart
18/04/14 23:34:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 69: [: Mac.out: integer expression expected
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-seanplowman-namenode-Seans
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class Mac.log

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 69: [: Mac.out: integer expression expected
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-seanplowman-datanode-Seans
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class Mac.log

Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 69: [: Mac.out: integer expression expected
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-seanplowman-secondarynamenode-Seans
0.0.0.0: Error: Could not find or load main class Mac.log

18/04/14 23:35:08 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 60: [: Mac.out: integer expression expected
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-seanplowman-resourcemanager-Seans
Error: Could not find or load main class Mac.log

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 60: [: Mac.out: integer expression expected
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-seanplowman-nodemanager-Seans
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class Mac.log
```

jps also says that none of the nodes are up after running the start scripts. From what I have researched it seems like it may be something wrong with my hostnames however trying to change those hasn't fixed anything.

I will provide my other config files to show how they are setup for context.

## /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose scheme and 
  authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The uri's scheme determines 
  the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming the FileSystem implementation
  class.  The uri's authority is used to determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.
  </description>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

## /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

## /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:9010</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

I made a few changes to my hadoop-env.sh as well. I will put those below.

## /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
```

## .bashrc

```
#Hadoop variables
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native"
###end of paste
```

## .bash_profile

```
alias hstart="/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh;/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-yarn.sh"
alias hstop="/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/stop-yarn.sh;/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/stop-dfs.sh"
```

I'm not sure what the next step to take from here is having looked at pretty much every file involved.

Comment: First, the "Job tracker" doesn't exist in Hadoop2+  so what tutorial are you looking at that isn't the official Hadoop site?

Comment: Also, in the first block, something is messed up with your start scripts... `Mac.log` and `Mac.out` aren't the default file names

Comment: I did a fresh reinstall of hadoop 2.9.0 and followed Apache's tutorial at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html. I got to the point where I was before but the `localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 69: [: Mac.out: integer expression expected` no longer appears. I still have the same error with not being able to find Mac.log. And I have no clue where that comes from.

Comment: `hadoop-daemon.sh: line 69` or `yarn-daemon.sh: line 60` what are they doing? What variables are being used?

Comment: Also, no part of that page says to set `mapred.job.tracker`, so where did you get that information?

Comment: That was from a separate tutorial that I am no longer using. I got rid of changes to `mapred-site.xml`. I re-downloaded hadoop and have only made changes to `core-site.xml` `hdfs-site.xml` and `hadoop-env.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have spaces in your Mac's hostname. For example, `Seans Mac`

The default log files are named using that,

HDFS: `log=$HADOOP_LOG_DIR/hadoop-$HADOOP_IDENT_STRING-$command-$HOSTNAME.out`
YARN: `log=$YARN_LOG_DIR/yarn-$YARN_IDENT_STRING-$command-$HOSTNAME.out`

Where `$HOSTNAME` is the issue, and spaces are unexpected.

If you look at the output, you'll notice `hadoop-seanplowman-namenode-Seans`, so I suspect

`HADOOP_IDENT_STRING` = user running the scripts = `seanplowman`
`command` = `hadoop`
`HOSTNAME` = `Seans Mac`

See if [fixing the hostname](http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/06/change-your-mac-hostname-via-terminal/) without spaces changes anything.

If not, edit the `yarn-daemon.sh` and `hadoop-daemon.sh` scripts to start with

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -xv
```

Then edit the question with the outputs

Comment: That was it! I was having some weird error earlier where my Terminal for my laptop thought it was called "collins ipad" and I tried to change it but put a space. That fixed it right up.

Comment: Welcome. By the way, if you want to get up and running with a better Hadoop environment, I might suggest checking out tutorials by Hortonworks or Cloudera and using their prebuilt Virtual Machines